# Referencing calculated value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I wonder why this doesn't work (in PostgreSQL):

```
create table t(c integer);
insert into t values(1);
insert into t values(2);
insert into t values(3);

select c+10 as result from t group by result order by result;
--> OK
select c+10 as result from t where result > 10;
--> ERROR:  column "result" does not exist
```

So I can refer to column result in group by and in order by, but not in where. Why is that?

This is just a simplified example. In the real thing there is a function in select-part. I need the result of that function in where-part. I wouldn't like to calculate the function twice. What would be the best way to do this (as for the example above, how to avoid calculate c+10 twice)?

Comment: It is because of the sequence of the query parts processing (don't remember exactly but something like): `from, where`(`select` part still not available) `-> select -> group by, order by` (`select` part available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LATERAL`:

```
SELECT result 
FROM t
,LATERAL (SELECT c+10) AS s(result)  -- here you calculate what you need
WHERE result > 10;
```

Then you could refer to calculated value in `SELECT/WHERE/ORDER BY...` clauses.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6dc21/2/0)**</kbd>

---

Simplified execution order:

[image]

<sup>Image from: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx</sup>

As you see `WHERE` is before `SELECT` that is why you cannot refer to calculated expression in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a column alias on the level where you define it. You need to wrap that in a derived table:

```
select *
from (
    select c+10 as result 
    from t 
) x 
where result > 10;
```

There is no performance impact for this, it's merely syntactic sugar